# Temporarily keep iCarousel from scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, icarousel

Is there some way to prevent iCarousel from scrolling? Like, a "lock screen" feature? When i press a button, it should stop scrolling and when the button is pressed a second time, it'll start scrolling again. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The carousel uses a pan gesture recogniser to control the scrolling. If you get access to that gesture you can disable it (and then re-enable it again later).

Comment: After experimentation and much deliberation i've discovered that this was the solution to my problem. I edited the iCarousel.m file and added a function that returned the panGesture instance. Then i used this code to enable/disable scrolling: panGesture.enabled = NO; / panGesture.enabled = YES;.

Comment: Why would you do that? iCarousel.m already has a variable UIPangesturerecognizer and you could make a public property from that and disable/Enable it. But non of these solutions has worked really. it still doesnt do anything @Katushai

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to prevent the user from interacting with the carousel then simply write

`[carousel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`

To start scrolling then the first button is pressed write:

```
-(IBAction) spinButton:(id)sender {

   [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:30 duration:10];

}
```

To stop scrolling then the second button is pressed write:

```
-(IBAction) stopButton:(id)sender {

[carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:[carousel currentItemIndex] animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: The first solution disabled all user interaction, including button presses on any screens. The second solution was just a method of having the carousel scroll through all items automatically. Thank you all for your answers, though. It was all very helpful in my research toward solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by:

```
[carousel setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: this solved my problem but I suggest reenable it in the next line: `[carousel setScrollEnabled:YES];` otherwise at least in my case it causes some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this view property to NO:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL userInteractionEnabled
```

It will disable touch handling of your carousel view.

Comment: This solved my problem but in addition to not scrolling, it also disabled all buttons on any of the screens.